# Run the query nd found the ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying this query but found the error on &CLEARED_FLAG

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
SELECT vch_locn_code
      ,vch_vch_type
      ,vch_vch_#
      ,vch_srl_#
      ,vch_bank_code
      ,vch_instrmt_type
      ,vch_instrmt_num
      ,vch_instrmt_date
      ,vch_instrmt_amt
      ,vch_drawn_at
      ,vch_payable_at
      ,vch_dshnr_flag
      ,vch_rcln_flag
      ,vch_rcln_date
      ,vch_trns_type
      ,vch_payee_name
      ,vch_bv_date
      ,vch_clear_date
      ,dd_no
      ,dd_dt
      ,cleared_dt
  FROM fac_vch_bv
 WHERE vch_bv_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date
   AND vch_locn_code = :locn_code
   AND vch_vch_# IN (SELECT DISTINCT vch_vch_#
                       FROM fac_vch_d
                      WHERE vch_gl_code = :bank_code
                        AND vch_dbcr = (SELECT decode(:bank_receipt, 'Y', 'D', 'N', 'C') FROM dual)
                        AND vch_vch_type = '0102')
   AND vch_vch_# IN (SELECT vch_vch_#
                       FROM fac_vch_m
                      WHERE vch_vch_type = '0102'
                        AND vch_bank_code = :bank_code) &cleared_flag
 ORDER BY vch_instrmt_num
         ,vch_instrmt_date
```

Comment: You know why you used an ampersand? It helps you only when the query is run in SQL*Plus..

Comment: Actually this is a Lexical Parameter..so use the ampersand..

Comment: I see, you use both lexical parameters and bind variables. How do you run this query? Means in any tool or jdbc.. ?

Comment: no i m using the Toad for run the queries.

Comment: just i remove the & symbole...sooo..:(

Comment: Try to run ur query as hard coded string values first of all. And then replace with the colon-ed bind variable names.

Comment: i hv already do this...this issue on vch_vch_type..i hv already replace with :vch_type...it's a Global Varibale..so,after this replace create the same error on &CLEARED_FLAG

Comment: So what value are you giving for `CLEARED_FLAG`? Are you being prompted for the substitution variable - maybe prompting is turned off in the options?

Comment: actually CLEARED_FLAG ih attached to BANK RECONCILIATION Form...From this parameter provide the cleared date of the cheques...

Comment: what is means of  "prompting is turned off in the options"